Adding 100amp subpanel in shed
In South Carolina, USA.
Planning to install a 100amp subpanel in my new shed (with grounding rod). And trying to figure out best cable to run.
My service panel is 200amp. Planning to put a 90amp breaker in there to run the subpanel service from.
I need to go about 55' through a crawlspace and 45' buried.
If I read everything correctly, I can use MHF 2-2-2-4 in conduit the whole way (with proper transitions from crawlspace to buried outside). Is that correct?
Thanks for any help or recommendations.

Have you done a load calculation to be sure your main panel has the excess capacity to add the 90A circuit?

@Milwrdfan great question. Yes. Calculating loads from all the appliances and such around the house, I'm currently sitting around 100amps. I'm running the 90amp breaker to the shed, but didn't really intend on needing close to that. Just leaving myself and some room. I have a table saw, and a few other tools. But won't be running them all at once at any point.

@Milwrdfan Panels are not loads. It's always perfectly legal to send an entire service to a sub-panel, regardless of loads in the main panel. Obviously the load calculation does dictate what loads can be serviced. And given the economical pricing of #2 MHF, there's not likely to be any savings from going smaller.

@nobody am i good with the 2 2 2 4 MHF?

Simple answer is yes. Provided that you tie into your power supply correctly. The wire is correct for the size panel you are installing. You would still have to consider your load capacity for your house 90 amps vs 200 amp house. There would be a possibility of over amping if everything was running at the same time.

Thanks. I still think I'm good, but you guys have me second guessing myself now. LOL. I'm going to run through everything again. Even if i go with a slightly lower amp breaker, i will probably still run the 2 2 2 4 so i don't have to worry about it I'm the future.
